# What is the difference between copy and paste a file using command line terminal and GUI copy paste?

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, terminal, c

What is the difference between copy and paste a file using command line terminal and GUI copy paste ? Which one is fast ? I think both are same because of same program will execute in background .

What am i asking is, in windows or linux ...i want to copy a directory from one directory to another. To do that i may use command line (cp command in linux or copy command in windows) or directly i can copy the directory by right click and paste in destination directory right click-> paste. Now my question which process is fast/efficient. Or both are same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which process is fast/efficient depends on whether it's faster for you to type the command in command line or faster to drag and drop files around. They are identical in they way the files are transferred as far as speed and efficiency.

Comment: You can arguments to copy files in bulk. If you want to overwrite some files, you can tell the command line to input to say yes to every question. There is a silent trigger in copy commands that disable any message.

Answer (score 0):

dude from terminal is much faster than the gui, why? resources/process from grapics, etc

*more resources*

```
cp -v file to file
```

*less resources*

```
cp file to file
```

if you have a old pc this is the way.